# Regex - get the position of regex unmatched

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for generic code that will give me the unmatched position of the input string.

```
public static boolean patternMatch(final String patternToMatch, final String valueToMatch){
        if (null == patternToMatch || null == valueToMatch){
            LOGGER.debug(String.format("Either patternToMatch(%s) or valueToMatch(%s) is null",patternToMatch,valueToMatch));
        }

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternToMatch);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(valueToMatch);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

This is the code given regex and value, checks if the value matches the regular expression. If it does not match wanted to throw Exception saying "the match failed at position <>".

How to get the position of un-match. Regular expression can be anything. Any algorithm to get it?

Thanks

Comment: The position where the match failed is **index 0**. Since regex uses backtracing to try various matching options, it's impossible for regex to pinpoint a single point of failure. What you're asking cannot be done.

Comment: Okay. How does the regex tester give us the portion of value that matches ?

Comment: No idea, since I've no idea what tester you're talking about. Your question is about the **Java** regex engine. It cannot do what you ask.

Comment: @Aavik do you think  i answered your question, do you have other doubts ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `matcher.matches()` which matches the whole subject string , so there is no single portion which does not match the whole target string  is not matching and when it is matched the whole target string is matched and i you want you can get the matched value.

As you asked in the comment **how to get the matched value?**
for that purpose you can call `matcher.group()` after calling the `mathcer.matches()` but as the `matches()` method matches the whole string so `matches.group()` will return  you whole string and if it doesn't match it will throw an exception.

if you want to match the part of the regex you will need to use `find()` method then the group() will return only matched part.

**ex**

```
String s = "this is a cat";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bcat\\b").matcher(s);
        m.find();
        System.out.println(m.group());
```

above code prints "cat" because cat is the matched part but if you use `m.matches()` and then try to call `m.grounp()`  i will throw `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` and whole string if mathces.

Have a good day